# Minkowski's inequality

Tags: inequality

Minkowski's inequality says the following: For every sequence of scalars $a = (a_i)$ and $b = (b_i)$, and for $1 \leq p \leq \infty$ we have: $||a+b||_{p} \leq ||a||_{p}+ ||b||_{p}$. Note that $||x||_{p} = \left(\smash{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}} |x_i|^{p}\right)^{1/p}$. This is how I tried proving it:
\begin{align*}
||a+b||^{p} &= \sum |a_k+b_k|^{p}\\\
&\leq \sum(|a_k|+|b_k|)^{p}\\\
&= \sum(|a_k|+|b_k|)^{p-1}|a_k|+ \sum(|a_k|+|b_k|)^{p-1}|b_k|.
\end{align*}

From here, how would you proceed? I know that you need to use Hölder's inequality. So maybe we can bound both the sums on the RHS since they are products.

Comment: instead of using `$\displaymath...$` you can use `$$...$$` to get displayed math; and macros like `\begin{align}` to get aligned equations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Holder's Inequality would say that
$$\sum |x_ky_k| \leq \left(\sum |x_k|^r\right)^{1/r}\left(\sum|y_k|^s\right)^{1/s}$$
where $\frac{1}{r}+\frac{1}{s}=1$.

Apply Holder's twice, once to each sum, using $x_k = a_k$, $y_k = (|a_k|+|b_k|)^{p-1}$ in one, and similarly in the other, with $r=p$ and $\frac{1}{s}=1-\frac{1}{p}$.

Comment: I think we should apply holder to $y_k=(|a_k+b_k|)^{p-1}$ and OP should not apply triangle inequality to $|a_k+b_k|^{p-1}$. Thanks