# Prove that Euclidean distance in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a distance

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, metric-spaces

I'm trying to show that:
$$\forall x,y\in\mathbb{R}^n, d(x,y)=\left(\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-y_i)^2\right)^{1/2}$$

is a distance. However I have not proved Cauchy-Schwarz yet and I'm pretty sure I wouldn't know how to use it in this case. Can someone give me a hint on how to solve this?

Thanks a lot for helping!!!

Comment: I think you might be able to prove it using induction over the dimension $n$ using just the Pythagorean Theorem and an argument that any line in $\mathbb{R^{n-1}}$ is orthogonal to the axis along the coordinate in $\mathbb{R^{n}}$ that is not in $\mathbb{R^{n-1}}$ (i.e. the $n$-th coordinate). E.g. lines in $xy$-plane are all orthogonal to $z$-axis.

Comment: @Marconius Thanks for your comment, but I am still not sure how to do it. Would you be so kind to explain your idea a little more? Thanks! :D

Comment: @GuilhermeSalomé,have you seen Cauchy -Schwarz proof?https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality

Comment: Are you allowed to use $||\mathbf{v}|| = \sqrt{\langle\mathbf{v},\mathbf{v}\rangle}$?

Comment: see e.g. [1](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17625/proof-of-triangle-inequality-on-mathbbrn-d-p?rq=1), [2](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/91181/proof-for-triangle-inequality-for-vectors)

Comment: @Marconius i think so!

Comment: See also: [Proof for triangle inequality for vectors](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/91181)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$ \sum_i (x_i + \lambda y_i)^2\geqslant 0 $$
$$ \sum_i x_i^2+\lambda x_iy_i +\lambda x_iy_i+\lambda^2y_i^2 \geqslant0 $$
Let $\lambda=-(\sum_jx_jy_j)/(\sum _jy_jy_j)$ then:
$$\sum_i x_i^2-\frac{(\sum_ix_iy_i)(\sum_jx_jy_j)}{(\sum _jy_jy_j)}-\frac{(\sum_ix_iy_i)(\sum_jx_jy_j)}{(\sum _jy_jy_j)}+(\frac{\sum_jx_jy_j}{\sum _jy_j^2})^2 \sum_iy_i^2 \geqslant0$$

Simplifying and adjusting the terms on both sides of the inequality yields:
$$(\sum_i x_iy_i)^2 \leqslant  \sum_i x_i^2 \sum_iy_i^2  \tag{cqfd!}$$ 
**EDIT**
Now to  the triangle inequality:

$$\sum_i(x_i+y_i)^2=\sum_i x_i^2 +2\sum_i x_iy_i + \sum_iy_i^2 \leqslant \sum_ix_i^2 +2\sqrt{\sum_ix_i^2 \sum_iy_i^2} +\sum_iy_i^2$$
$$=(\sqrt{\sum_ix_i^2} + \sqrt{\sum_iy_i^2} )^2 \tag{cqfd!}$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But how do I go from this to Minkowski?

Comment: In other words, how do I go from your inequality to the triangle inequality for that distance?

Comment: @GuilhermeSalomé I've written the triangle inequality, which is a particular case of the Minkowski inequality (to my knowledge, it needs the Holder inequality to be proven)

Answer (score 0):

Put $\mathbf{v} = \mathbf{x} - \mathbf{y}$

Then

$d(x,y) = \|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}\| = \|\mathbf{v}\|$

and

$\langle{\mathbf{v},\mathbf{v}}\rangle = \langle{\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y},\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}}\rangle = \displaystyle{\sum\limits_i^n(x_i-y_i)^2}$

and so $\|v\| = \sqrt{\langle\mathbf{v},\mathbf{v}\rangle}$ implies the desired result.